# Python, Data Frame into PDF

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pdf, converters

I have a nice data frame that I need to convert into PDF file. I tried to use weasyprint library but I had a problem to change this into html in a correct way. Do you have any idea how I could fix my issue ?

Below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from weasyprint import HTML
import fpdf

name_company = 'INDYKPOL'


url = f"https://www.bankier.pl/gielda/notowania/akcje/{name_company}/podstawowe-dane"


page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')

#Find the second table on the page
t = soup.find_all('table')[0]

df = pd.read_html(str(t))[0]

x = pd.DataFrame.to_html(df)
```

Data Frame looks like below:

```
               0                                             1
0  Nazwa spółki:                                   Indykpol SA
1        Prezes:                              Kulikowski Piotr
2        Sektor:                                       żywność
3           EKD:  przetwarzanie i konserwowanie mięsa z drobiu
4  Liczba akcji:                                     3 124 500
5  Zatrudnienie:  999 (2017r.) - spółka 1 218 (2017r.) - grupa
6       Audytor:                       BDO PL sp. z o.o. sp.k.
```

Do you have ani idea how I could save this into PDF ? There could be anyway. Thanks All for help !

Comment: ok, i got this. First create df into html and than I can use pdfkit:
config = pdf.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="D:\\wkhtmltox\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe")
pdf.from_file('table.html', 'sdfgsf.pdf',configuration=config)